# accelerometer sensor and mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

with your help and some guides on the internet, i'm managed to knock out this code. But I find myself with several problems, the application, according to my idea, it should start the media player at the time the phone is shaken, and start it once, but now the media player is started every time the phone is shaken . Furthermore, I would like that, the application worked and the screen off when the phone is shaken starts the media player and the screen is turned on

```
public class SensorTestActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private boolean color = false;
private View view;
private long lastUpdate;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
view = findViewById(R.id.textView);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.registerListener(this,
sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
getAccelerometer(event);
}
}
private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
float[] values = event.values;
// Movement
float x = values[0];
float y = values[1];
float z = values[2];

float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)/(SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH *    SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
{
if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
return;
}
lastUpdate = actualTime;
Toast.makeText(this, "Device was shuffed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if (color) {
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

try { 

mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.mymusic);

mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
mMediaPlayer.start();
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new
OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
// if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
// mMediaPlayer.release();
// mMediaPlayer = null;
// }
}
});
} catch (Exception e) {
if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
mMediaPlayer.release();
mMediaPlayer = null;
}
}                   
}
} else {
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
color = !color;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
// register this class as a listener for the orientation and
// accelerometer sensors
sensorManager.registerListener(this,
sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
// unregister listener
super.onPause();
sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start something just once, add a boolean.

```
boolean startOnce = true;

if (startOnce) {
 ....
 startOnce = false;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but where in my code i must insert the boolean variable with "if" structure?